# JQUery Validate not executed on Click Event

Tags: jquery

greetings,

Could any one tell me what am I doing wrong on code below. It's not executing on Click. I'm quiet note sure wether `$("form").validate` on applies to Submit button:

jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Form Submit
            $('#ClockOutBtn').click(function () {
                $("form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        name: "required", // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
                        email: {// compound rule
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        url: {
                            url: true
                        },
                        comment: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        comment: "Please enter a comment."
                    }
                });
            });



        });
```

HTNML:

```
<fieldset>
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL</span><input type="text" name="url" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your comment *</span><textarea name="comment" ></textarea></div>

      <button id="ClockOutBtn" type="button"/>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

better than onClick I think is on form submit:

```
    $("form").bind('submit',function(){
        this.validate( etc... )
        if(valid_criteria)
            return true // submit
        else
            return false // don't submit
    })
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't have submit type button. It needs to be an image (could not show here as it said spam). It needs to be click event of image.

Comment: A submit button can also be styled as an image. You need to include an background-image via css.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, your `<input>` fields have no IDs and the validate function matches the names with the IDs from the `<input>` fields. Also I don't see any `<form>` tag around your `<input>` fields so you can't say `$("form")....`

EDIT:

- You don't need a `click` Event for your button, because the plugin handle this automatically when the submit button is clicked.
- each input field needs an id
- you need to include the jQuery library for the validate plugin
- you need to have a `<form>` tag around your input field

Have a look at this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvXug/6/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    $("#ClockOutBtn").click(function(){
        $("#testForm").validate({
                     rules: {
                         name: "required", // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
                         email: {// compound rule
                             required: true,
                             email: true
                         },
                         url: {
                             url: true
                         },
                         comment: {
                             required: true
                         }
                     },
                     messages: {
                         comment: "Please enter a comment."
                     }
                 });
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="testForm">
<fieldset>
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL</span><input type="text" name="url" id="url" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your comment *</span><textarea name="comment" id="comment" ></textarea></div>

    <button id="ClockOutBtn">Test</button>


    </fieldset>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It's mvc application and I did not put form tags but on actual web application its there. I want to validate the Form when user clicks Image. I can't have Submit button as I have not figured out how to put image on submit button.

Comment: I changed my answer so that the example works on click event.